# How to show one result per question on search?

Tags: support, search

Let's say that I search for keyword `X`. Search results will show me all questions or answers that contain `X` in them.

However, this means that for a given question `Q`, if `X` is present in both the question part of `Q` and an answer to `Q`, search will show me two results.

Is there way to configure the search, so that in such a scenario, search will show only one result?

Comment: You could try `is:q` to only have questions in the result?

Comment: @rene true, this fits as answer, it's not trivial or common knowledge.

Comment: I'm not sure @sha because I think it also limits the searched posts to only questions which might not be what the OP want, hence my comment.

Comment: @rene Not sufficient. I need the case where the keyword is not present in the question part, but in one or more of the answers.

Comment: So I really have no idea what you ask here. Examples might help.

Comment: But which result do you want in that case @Utku? You only want to see the question, even if the search term is in an answer, right?

Comment: @rene It doesn't matter actually. In that case, showing the question or answer (but not both) would be sufficient.

Comment: Questions and Answers are just posts and if any search term matches they are put in the result. There is no distinct operator or something like that.

Comment: @rene So it is not possible right?

Comment: Unless there is some hidden switch I'm not aware of this is not possible.

Comment: @Utku: You can only perform certain *limited* actions through search. See [the page on searching in the Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more details on search operations. If you want a more detailed search, then you'll have to write a query in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Each post is a distinct *document*, so this sort of filtering tends to be hard with most search backends (I think StackExchange uses ElasticSearch?).

The typical solution to this problem in search engines, such as those of catalogues, is to allow *facets* and to group similar results. The latter should be easy enough for posts: they would only need to add a field to their search backend (if not available yet), i.e. the parent post ID (question ID), group all search results by that field, show  the highest scoring match.

Comment: But currently, there is no way to show results in that way right?

Comment: @Utku not that I know, other than by filtering by is:question as was said (which is not what you asked).